# Strings Or Macros in C#

Tags: c#

there are more that 90+  files(.cs) in my Application.

I have used a statement like

```
string str = MyMessages.IDS_STR_STRING1; 
MyMessages.IDS_STR_STRING2; 
MyMessages.IDS_STR_STRING3;
```

in many files almost say some 40+ files.

Where MyMessages is a static class.

I now have added another function in this class say GetMyString(string identifier).
So now the above statmenets would change to

```
MyMessages.GetMyString("IDS_STR_STRING1"); 
MyMessages.GetMyString("IDS_STR_STRING2"); 
MyMessages.GetMyString("IDS_STR_STRING3");
```

and so on....

Now searching and replacing each statement is tedious and could lead to manual errors. 
Can i write any macro / a tool that would find the string and replace in the appropriate format ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Replace function in Visual Studio which supports regex'es.

Something like:

*Input*

```
// search for a whitespace character, then the string 'MyMessages.'
//  match the next group of characters that is a word (a-zA-Z) or an _
//  and capture it into group number 1
\sMyMessages\.([\w_]+);
```

*Replace*

```
// Replace it with 'MyMessages.GetMyString("', then insert group 1
// then add '");' to the string.
MyMessages.GetMyString("\1");
```

Comment: The parameter in GetMystring function should be the the string found after the "." ... what is

Comment: $1 in the statment MyMessages.GetMyString("$1");